# Cumulative Unique words in huge dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

How do I get  cumulative unique words from a dataframe column which has more than 500 words per. Dataframe has ~300,000 rows

I read the csv file in a dataframe with column A having text data.
I have tried creating couple of columns (B & C) by looping through column A and taking unique words from column A as set and appending Column B with unique words and Column C with count

Subsequently, I  take unique words by taking Column A and column B(union) from previous row(set)

This works for small number of rows. But once number of rows exceeds 10,000 performance degrades and kernal eventually dies

Is there any better way of doing this for huge dataframe ?

Tried creating seperate dataframe with just unique words and count, but still have issue

Sample code:

```
for index, row in DF.iterrows():
      if index = 0:
          result = set(row['Column A'].lower().split()
          DF.at[index, 'Column B'] = result
      else:
          result = set(row['Column A'].lower().split()
          DF.at[index, 'Cloumn B'] = result.union(DF.loc[index -1, 
                                                'Column B'])
DF['Column C'] = DF['Column B'].apply(len)
```

Comment: post your code, do not describe it. Also post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, posted code

Comment: So you only want all the unique values of 'A Column' from the dataframe?

Comment: Cumulative Unique value from Column A, and cumulative unique word count from  Column A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exploit uniqueness of dictionary keys to cumulate words.

I create a dict `cumulative_words` where I want to store unique words row by row, by updating it with dictionaries having keys made of unique words from a given row sentence.

**Code:**

```
cumulative_words = {}

def cumulate(x):
    cumulative_words.update(dict.fromkeys(set(x.lower().split())))
    return list(cumulative_words.keys())

df["Column B"] = df["Column A"].apply(cumulate)
df["Column C"] = df["Column B"].apply(len)
```

---

### Update:

Given that you said this code still has memory issues at ~ 200k rows,
I'll try something very simple to understand a bit more:

1. **Just update the dictionary of cumulatives**

Create the dictionary with unique words before dataframe operations

```
cumulative_words = {}

for x in df["Column A"].values:
    cumulative_words.update(dict.fromkeys(set(x.lower().split())))
```

If this still breaks I think we have to change method

2. **Append words to a list**

This is the critical point I think, because it creates a list of lists of, roughly, billions of words

```
cumulative_words = {}
cumulative_column = []

for x in df["Column A"].values:
    cumulative_words.update(dict.fromkeys(set(x.lower().split())))
    cumulative_column.append(cumulative_words.keys())
```

3. **Assign created list to Column B and count**

```
df["Column B"] = cumulative_column
df["Column C"] = df["Column B"].apply(len)
```

Maybe there are just too many words to store and a dataframe can't be created, or I don't know how to do. Let me know

Comment: Solution from Lante provided better result than my previous attempts. Not perfect since it still breaks at ~ 200K rows

Comment: Glad you appreciated my option, but I'm curious, what happens when it breaks?

Comment: Either kernel dies or Memory Error while running in Jupyter notebook

Comment: I added a couple of things I'd do

Answer (score 0):

You could use CountVectorizer and make the cumulative sum afterwards.

Learn more about CountVectorizer : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html
And pandas' cumulative sum : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html

Comment: CountVectorizer works only if I have to get unique words count for each column. I need to get cumulative words for all previous rows in column B. getting sum is relatively easy when I words though

Comment: Could you provide a data sample to test your code ?